# Cloudstack without using vCenter

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, apache-cloudstack, vmware-server, vcenter

I want to deploy 10-15 VMWare hosts to cloudstack. This is my first time working with any type of cloud. I was doing research on installation and architecture, I was stuck on a point that for using VMWare hosts i have to install VCenter server, but i can't do that as it's paid. So, please guide me that is there a way of deploying these VMWare hosts on cloudstack without buying any licensed software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, CloudStack does not support vSphere/ESXi without vCenter. There were several requests to support vSphere/ESXi without vCenter - however, keep in mind that many features vCenter provides must be implemented in CloudStack and it not an easy task.

If you want to remain open source and or/free, consider using Xen with XenCenter or just go pure KVM. I use to use VMware for most of my career and recently transitions to KVM - it was an easy switch and with no regrets.

CloudStack mailing lists are best to answering any setup questions you might have.

All best
-ilya

Answer (score 1):

By design, vCenter is must for CloudStack to manage & build cloud over VMware ESXi hosts. It would be huge exercise to extend the support to ESXi host management without vCenter, which could be limited in features like live migration, VMware distributed virtual switches, DRS etc.

You might consider switching to XenServer which is free and very well supported seamlessly by CloudStack. Feel free discuss your deployment configuration and planning at `users@cloudstack.apache.org` or `dev@cloudstack.apache.org`.